# How to configure Xcode to ignore analyze warnings in select files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings, profile

I know that I can ignore compiler warnings with `-w` on a given file in Xcode.

I would like to similarly ignore analyze warnings on a given file (JSONKit.m in this case, which has two potential leaks). I trust that the developer of that library knows what they're doing, and I don't want to maintain a fork of it. Not to mention that I have no clue what's going on in there anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Don't trust the developer.   Figure out why the potential leaks exist and fix them (ideally, sending a patch back to the developer).

If you want to take the lazy way out (j/k ;), you can add code to fix the problem under the analyzer only using:

```
#ifdef __clang_analyzer__
... release the offending variable here ...
#endif
```

I prefer this solution to whole-file-disabling because it both exactly identifies the problem area with an easily searchable identifier and it allows the rest of the file to be vetted by the constantly improving analyzer.